# Mysql suddenly stopped working. Using XAMPP VM on mac

Tags: mysql, xampp-vm

Suddenly mysql stopped working. I use XAMPP VM on mac. I'm pretty new to both mac and XAMPP VM.

Previously used XAMPP on Windows.

In the browser (localhost:8080/phpmyadmin) displays "Unable to connect: invalid settings!

```
The command sudo service mysql start
```

in the VM terminal gives

> Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.

The command `mysql -u root -p` gives

> "Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket".

Comment: the main thing is to check mysql error log, which will tell you why the server is not starting

Comment: ERROR: Failed to restart "mysql": cannot start service: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process

Comment: that is not the mysql error log, look where it is located which the name of your operating system